# Justification C++

Tags: c++, cout

I can't seem to get my data to stay in the correct spot. It originally worked, however when I transfered my code to my home computer, the justification went way off. Can anyone help me out??

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <ctime>
#include "fixgets.c"

using namespace std;

int main (void)
{
int userID, blackhole_mass, radius, totalMass=0;
long int date;
char blackhole_name[16];
char FirstName[11];
char LastName[16];

time(&date);


FILE *blackholeFile;

if ((blackholeFile = fopen( "Holter.txt", "r")) == NULL)
{
cout << "File could not be opened" << endl;
}

//Heading

cout << setw(12) << "\n'Schwartzchild Radius Database' by Jonathan Holter" << setw(4)            
<< " " << ctime(&date);



cout << left;
cout << setw(12) << "First Name"
<< setw(11) << "Last Name" << setw(9)  << "User ID" << setw(17) << "Black Hole Name" <<    
setw(17) << "Black Hole Mass" << "Schwartzchild Radius" << endl << endl;


fixgets(FirstName,11,blackholeFile);
fixgets(LastName,16,blackholeFile);
fscanf(blackholeFile,"%d\n", &userID);
fixgets(blackhole_name,16,blackholeFile);
fscanf(blackholeFile,"%d\n", &blackhole_mass);

while (!feof (blackholeFile))
{

radius = blackhole_mass * 2;

totalMass += blackhole_mass;

cout << left << setw(12) << FirstName << setw(11) << LastName << right
<< setw(9)  << userID << left << "  " << setw(17) << blackhole_name
<< right << setw(10) << blackhole_mass << setw(22) << radius << endl << endl << endl;

fixgets(FirstName,11,blackholeFile);
fixgets(LastName,16,blackholeFile);
fscanf(blackholeFile,"%d\n", &userID);
fixgets(blackhole_name,16,blackholeFile);
fscanf(blackholeFile,"%d", &blackhole_mass);

}

cout << right << setw(48) << "  " << setw(10) << right << "Total Amount of Mass 
Recorded:  " << totalMass;

fclose(blackholeFile);
return 0;
}
```

This is a copy of my code.

Comment: Do you mean code alignment ?

Comment: No, actual text alignment when the data is displayed on the console.

Comment: what editor are you using ? on linux or windows ?

Comment: Knowing what output you expect and what output you actually get would be helpful, "went way off" could mean just about anything.

Comment: I want all the info being printed to be in columnar form. Before I moved my code file, it was printing perfectly.

Comment: And how's it printing now? You posted a program nobody can compile and run, so you have to tell us these things.

Comment: Don't use tabs.  Use fixed pitch font with spaces.

Comment: The program is printing the first name in the last name column, the black hole mass in the s. radius column, etc

Comment: Insufficient information to diagnose problem.

Comment: Opinion: When writing C++, *write C++*. What you have here is extraordinarily dangerous C code using fixed size string buffers and repeated use of buffer size literals which are very easy to get wrong. You have also included a .c file which is almost always wrong. It is just very, very wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You are already using `FILE*` and `scanf` functions. I recommend going all the way back to C input AND output functions. Use `printf`. It is much easier to control the formatting and in my opinion more readable too.